# Making indicator variables out of lists in r

Tags: r, reshape, indicator

I'm having a data reshaping problem that I could use some help.

```
 ID          X1         X2         X3         X4         X5
6001 Certificate  Associate Bachelor's   Master's   Doctoral
5001 Certificate  Associate Bachelor's           
3311 Certificate  Associate Bachelor's           
1981 Certificate  Associate Bachelor's   Master's
4001   Associate Bachelor's   Master's           
2003   Associate Bachelor's   Master's   Doctoral
2017 Certificate  Associate                      
1001   Associate Bachelor's   Master's           
5002  Bachelor's
```

I need to make these into dummy variables

```
  ID    Certificate     Associates      Bachelor         Master        Doctoral      
6001              1              1             1              1               1
5001              1              1             1              0               0 
2017              1              1             0              0               0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `reshape2` package. I've assumed your dataset is called `df`:

```
require(reshape2)
# First, melt your data, using 
m.df = melt(df, id.vars="ID")
# Then `cast` it
dcast(m.df, ID ~ value, length)
#     ID Var.2 Associate Bachelor's Certificate Doctoral Master's
# 1 1001     2         1          1           0        0        1
# 2 1981     1         1          1           1        0        1
# 3 2003     1         1          1           0        1        1
# 4 2017     3         1          0           1        0        0
# 5 3311     2         1          1           1        0        0
# 6 4001     2         1          1           0        0        1
# 7 5001     2         1          1           1        0        0
# 8 5002     4         0          1           0        0        0
# 9 6001     0         1          1           1        1        1
```

I haven't tested it, but if you make your factors ordered, it might control the order of the  output columns.

Comment: Works beautifully! May I ask, why length as a parameter for cast?

Comment: `length` is default--just counts the number of times it occurs for that group. It's tabulation in `cast`. To see how it works, substitute  `Associate` with a second `Bachelor's` to ID `6001` (`df[1,3] = "Bachelor's"`). When you melt and reshape, that row would then read `0 2 1 1 1`. With the way your data is, it shouldn't be a problem, but it might also help identify if there were any data entry errors!